# Create Entity Framework Seed method from existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We're in the process of converting a 15-year-old application into C#/Entity Framework Code First.

I've been able to create a migration for the table structures that I'll need, and I'd like to fill them with the data from our old application. Of course, it's possible to simply create a script using Management Studio, but I'd like to leverage Code First if possible.

I see that it's possible to [reverse engineer a database schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj200620). **Is there a simple way that I could generate a migration or Seed method from existing data in a database?** I'm not too worried about performance - it's enough data to be a pain to recreate by hand, but neither are we talking about thousands of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework itself should not be used for mass insertion/deletion/updating of records since the performance is really poor. If you want the seeding to be part of your migrations then you could include your `SqlCommands` inside your `Seed` method:

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
{
   context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Command Here");
}
base.Seed(context);
```

Comment: I'm not too worried about performance - it's complex enough data to be a pain to recreate by hand, but neither are we talking about thousands of rows. I may just dump into all into a string literal, then, if that's really the best option.

Comment: is your data currently in a sql server db? if it is you could use the `Generate Scripts` feature.

Comment: That looks like the most reasonable option. Thanks.